# How to bring a background program to foreground

Tags: linux, shell

I am working on CentOS6, and running a django server for my development on a tmux session as：

**python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000**

So I can read my debug string print on it.

While there is an unknown reason which made my tmux session lost, and I cannot to bak to my working session using "tmux attach" command.

I still can find my server is running by ps command, but I have no permission to kill this in order to run a new server on the same port.

So, I want to call this backgound server to frontgound again.

As I never use ctrl+z or other ways to take process background, so even I use jobs command, there are no jobs.

But I dont know if I can do this, and how to do this...

Thanks all！！

Comment: there is no jobs. i have never used <ctrl>+z to make my running program to backgound, so fg doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry it is my fault that I forget my develop enviroment is a virtual machine on a pc, so actually the server is still running on my development pc. But I doubt that why I can find the running server info when I am using ps on the virtual machine's host machine?

Answer (score 12):

Use the `jobs` command to find the list of background processes that are started by you.
for eg: there is script which simply sleeps for 10 secs in 5 iterations.I ran it 4 times in the background.

```
>jobs
[1]  + Running                       ./temp.sh
[2]  - Running                       ./temp.sh
[3]    Running                       ./temp.sh
[4]    Running                       ./temp.sh
```

`fg` is the command to bring it back to the foreground as shown below.

```
>fg 1
[CTRL -c]
```

as seen above i have ended the process and it no longer exists.
now if i again run `jobs`

```
>jobs
[2]  + Running                       ./temp.sh
[3]    Running                       ./temp.sh
[4]  - Running                       ./temp.sh
>
```

Also you can check [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/running-background-process-and.html) for more

Comment: I suppose we can list processes under `jobs` only if it has be run in the background deliberately. ie - using `&` . Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `jobs` to obtain a list of your jobs, then you can use `fg <number of job>` to bring that job to the front.

Comment: there are no jobs. I never used <ctrl>+z or other way to make it to run background, so fg not work!